# A particular Lie algebra $L_{n}$ and (various) lie groups whose Lie algebra is isomorphic to $L_{n}$

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras, mathematical-finance, economics

**Edit:** According to the comment by @LSpice we realise the existing link to the main motivation of the question is not available. Then we search for the paper we found the following version:

https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Models-of-Consumer-Behaviour-Problem-presented-by-Schlijper/6e4edeaad6e400b4acee7a2ed180fb73dfa1f18e

And this link too:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277825529_Models_of_consumer_behaviour#fullTextFileContent

---

We  define $$L_{n}=\{A=(a_{ij})\in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})\mid \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{ij}=0 \;\;\;\text{for  every fixed j}\}$$
This  is  a Lie subalgebra of  $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$.

A dynamic-geometric proof for this fact is that;

$"$ The affine    hyper plane containing the standard simplex $\Delta^{n-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is invariant under the flow of a linear vector field $\dot X =AX,\;\; A\in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ if and only if $A\in L_{n}"$. On the other hand the space of all (linear) vector fields tangent to a submanifold  (say the affine hyper  plane containing $\Delta ^{n-1}$) of any manifold (say $\mathbb{R}^{n}$) is closed under Lie braket.

Is there any name-notation for this particular lie algebra? What is  a precise Lie group whose Lie  algebra is isomorphic to $L_{n}$? What is the precise description of the image of $L_{n}$ under the exponential map $A \mapsto e^{A}$?

What are some obstructions for  embedding  of  a  finite dimensional Lie  algebra in some $L_{n}$?

**Edited at Nov. 28, 2017, Motivation for  consideration of  such an  $L_n$:**

More than two years ago, an economist very kindlyintroduced me  [this paper](http://www.maths-in-industry.org/miis/38/1/Consumers.pdf) Model of consumer behaviour and suggests  me  to generalize the  mathematical part of the paper. My  observation was the  following fact as  generalization of the above paper:

**Fact:** The linear equation $X'=AX$ has  a unique equilibrium on the  standard simplex $\Delta^n$ if  $A=(a_{ij})$ belongs to $L_n$  and $a_{ij}>0\; \text{for}\; i\neq j$. Moreover the equilibrium is  an attractor singularity.

**Note:** In the linked paper, this fact is proved for $n=2,3$ with quite computational method.

**Sketch of Proof for arbitrary $n$:** The  system is a  monoton dynamical system since the off diagonal elements of  the  jacobian of the  vector  field is positive.

This implies that $\Delta^{n-1}$ is  flow  invariant. So the flow  version of the Leray Schauder fiexed point theorem implies that the  standard simplex has  at least one singularity. Now [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244042/is-this-a-full-rank-matrix?noredirect=1&lq=1) implies that the singularity is unique since the matrix $A$ is a matrix of rank $n-1$. To prove that the  singularity is attractor we use again the monotone property of the flow as follows.

Note that the  flow $\phi_t$ of  a  monotone dynamical system satisfies $x \leq y \implies \phi_t(x) \leq \phi_t(y)$. The  order  we  are  considering is defined as follows:

$$x\leq y \iff x_i \leq y_i,\;\; \forall i$$ where $x_i, y_i,s$ are coordinates  of $x,y$, respectively.

Now  we  prove that the  unique  singularity of $X'=AX$ in the standard simplex is  an  attractor singularity provided that $A \in L_n$ and its off diagonal entries are strictly positive.

Let $\ell$ be the one  dimensional subspace which determines the kernel of $A$. Then $\ell$ intersect the standard  simplex at point $p\in \Delta^{n-1}$. The point $p$ is the unique singularity of the system on the simplex. Lets choose a point $q \in \ell$ where $q$ is  near to $p$ and $\sum q_i<1$. We construct a cone with base point $q$. By monotone property of flow we conclude that this  cone is flow invariant. If we let $q$ approach to $p$, then we observe that $p$
is an stable singularity. By a  simple argument one can shows that the singularity can be approached  by a band  of  closed orbit because the  direction field on the boundary of the simplex is toward interior. So the unique singularity is attractor.

The " Monoton dynamical systems" is introduced by Morris W. Hirsch.

Here is  a  picture for  our proof:

[image]

Comment: Your link to "this paper" is now broken.

Comment: @LSpice yes I see. The title of the paper is "A model of consumer bahavior" I try to find another link containing this paper. On this paper they showed rhat for n=2 or 3 any such $A\in  L_n$ has a unique equilibrum on $\Delta^n$. They used the direct computational method. But the interesting gact is that for every $n$ we have a unique  atractive equilibrum in $\Delta^n$. The key point which was not observed by the authors of the linked paper is that the system satisfies the Hirsch competitive dynamical property(monoton dynamical system").  It is a little bizzare that yhe.linked paper doesnit

Comment: does not work(it is broken)

Comment: Is "A model of consumer behavior" the full title?  Who are the authors?

Comment: @LSpice Yes I just find i add to the revised version of question. Thank you for your attention

Comment: @LSpice  I just realize that it is no longer broken but it is changed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your Lie algebra consists of $X$ such that $Xv = 0$ where $v$ is the all-ones vector. So the corresponding Lie group in $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ consists of $g \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $gv = v$.

This is conjugate to the same group but where $v$ has been replaced with the vector $e_1 = (1, 0, 0, \dots) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, which is easier to deal with. The corresponding subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ consists of invertible matrices whose first column is $1, 0, 0, \dots$. This is the [general affine group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group). Abstractly it is the semidirect product $\mathbb{R}^{n-1} \rtimes GL_{n-1}(\mathbb{R})$ where the first factor comes from the first row and the second factor comes from the rest. By Ado's theorem every Lie algebra embeds into some $\mathfrak{gl}_{n-1}(\mathbb{R})$ and hence into the corresponding semidirect product.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think you mean $v^{tr}X=0$ ? So a related question: is every Lie  subalgebra  $L$ of $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ isomorphic to its transpose $L^{tr}$ while the transpose operator is not Lie  algebra automorphism?

Comment: @Ali: $X \mapsto - X^T$ is a Lie algebra automorphism of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$, which is the Lie algebra version of $g \mapsto (g^T)^{-1}$ being a Lie group automorphism of $GL_n$.

Comment: motivated by your answer, can one consider $\{ (v,g)\in S^{n-1}\times Gl(n)\mid g.v=v \}$, as total space of  a  natural fiber or principal fiber bundle over $S^{n-1}$?

Comment: In $GL_n$ the corresponding Lie group is $\mathbf{R}^{n-1}\rtimes GL_{n-1}^+(\mathbf{R})$ (which has index 2 in the non-connected $\mathbf{R}^{n-1}\rtimes GL_{n-1}(\mathbf{R})$). This group has a trivial center; its $\pi_1$ is the same as in the maximal compact subgroup $S0(n-1)$ which has $\pi_1$ of order $1$ if $n=2$, cyclic infinite if $n=3$, and of order 2 if $n\ge 4$. This allows to list those connected Lie groups having $L_n$ as Lie algebra.

Comment: @YCor  Thank you for your interesting comment which completes the answer. What about my other question in the previous comment?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  is my other question on the fiber bundle structure, obvious?Thanks again for your answer on my main question.

Comment: @Ali: I mean, I'm not sure what kind of answer you're expecting. Are you asking whether the map $(v, g) \to v$ is in fact a fiber bundle?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  Yes, the projection is that.The motivation for this question is your statment "This is conjucate to the same group but  where v replaced..."So the fibers are the same group and topological space(up to isomorphism and homemorphism) So is there a local trivialization  for  a fiber or principal fiber bundle structure?

Comment: @Ali: it's much simpler than that. If any group $G$ acts transitively on any set $X$, then the stabilizers of every $x \in X$ are conjugate: explicitly, if the stabilizer of $x$ is $H$, then the stabilizer of $gx$ is $gHg^{-1}$. This is elementary group theory.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  yes  this elementary. But how you apply this to my question. We have  a projection map from $\{(v,g)\in Gl(n)\times S^{n-1}\mid gv=v\}\to S^{n-1}$. Two questions:  is it a locally trivial fiber bundle?Can one construct a principal fiber bundle. In the latter we do not specify a certain group action. Could you please more explain?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  i realy do not know how to apply your comment to the questions.

Comment: @Ali: there is no need to think about this fiber bundle. Take $G = GL_n$ and take $X$ to be the $G$-set of nonzero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, on which $G$ acts transitively. All I am doing is changing coordinates.