# Is this a full rank matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

According to the  answer of  znt to the previous  version, I revise the  question as  follows:

Is there a real $(n-1)\times n$ matrix  $A$ 
such that $A$ is not a full rank matrix and satisfy $a_{ii}<0$ and $a_{ij}>0$ for $i \neq j$  and $\sum_{i}  a_{ij}<0$ for  every $j\leq n-1$.

A stronger  version:

> Is there  a  singular  $n\times n$  matrix $A$  such that diagonal  entries are negative, off diagonal  entries  are positive  and each  column sum up to a negative  number?

Comment: Sure there is. For example set $n=5$ and just make the sum of the first two rows equal the sum of the last two.

Comment: Is your matrix supposed to be $(n - 1) \times n$ (as in the original question) or $n \times n$ (as in the equivalent formulation)?

Comment: @LSpice  a sufficient condition for  full rankness of  $n-1 \times  n $  matrix is that every( or at least one)  $n-1 \times n-1$ submatrix would be  invertible. So putting $ n:=n-1$ leads to the  above  equivalent formulation.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E.   Thank  you. I revise the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, to your stronger question. If an $n \times n$ matrix satisfies the condition you specified, it would be a [strictly diagonally dominant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix#cite_note-3) which is non-singular.

Comment: I realy thank you very  much for your  answer.