# A certain subset of general linear group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, matrices, matrix-analysis

Motivated  by the concept of [diagonally  dominated  matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix#cite_note-3) we  consider the  space $S$   of  all complex $n\times n$  matrices with $|a_{ii}|>\sum_{j\neq i} |a_{ij}|$, for  every  $i$. [Every  element  of  $S$  is  invertible](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244042/is-this-a-full-rank-matrix)

> Is  $S$  a  connected  subset  of  $GL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$?What is its fundamental group?

One  can  consider the same  question for real  matrices  with  positive  determinant(to  avoid  disconnecte-ness)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can construct a homotopy retract of this to the set of diagonal matrices with nonzero diagonal entries by scaling nondiagonal entries to 0, and from there to a torus by scaling the diagonal entries to norm 1. Therefore, it is homotopy equivalent to $(S^1)^n$, and is connected.

For real matrices, the retract above still works, and takes you to $\{-1,1\}^n$.  The subset with positive determinant is the subset with product 1, and is not connected for $n>2$. I think the connected component you may want is the subset where all eigenvalues have positive real part, but have not checked.